# Jenkins 2.0: ansiblePlaybook plugin

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to execute a Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Deploy watchers') {
          ansiblePlaybook(
            playbook: "watcher-manage.yml",
            extraVars: [
              target: 'dev-dp-manager-1'
            ]
          )
        }
```

This produces `ansible-playbook watcher-manage.yml -e target=dev-dp-manager-1`.

This execution leads to:

```
fatal: [dev-dp-manager-1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

According to the documentation I need to add `sudo: true` to make the ansible command execute with root privileges. If I do so:

```
stage('Deploy watchers') {
          ansiblePlaybook(
            sudo: true,
            playbook: "watcher-manage.yml",
            extraVars: [
              target: 'dev-dp-manager-1'
            ]
          )
        }
```

This produces `ansible-playbook watcher-manage.yml -s -U root -e target=dev-dp-manager-1`. Nevertheless I get the same error.

If I try to say `sudo ansible-playbook ...` my command succeeds.
My question is whether I can achieve the desired execution by using the plugin or I have to write the ansible command by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: You should make required credentials (ssh keys) available for jenkins user.

Comment: I wouldn't like to do that since that would mean that the jenkins user on the machine must have access to all keys in .ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
stage('Deploy watchers') {
  sh 'sudo ansible-playbook watcher-manage.yml --extra-vars="target=dev-dp-manager-1"'
}
```

Since the Jenkins' linux user doesn't need have access to ssh keys, simply lifting its permissions for this one command does the job.

Comment: Oh man... If jenkins user can do `sudo` it can read any file on the server... You definitely need to review your permission model.